# Image file stretching in PDF by using php

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I am generating a PDF file having one LOGO, but the LOGO is stretching in the PDF file.

LOGO dimensions is: 612*91
I have added below code for this LOGO:

```
$pdf->Image(''.JURI::root().'images/myvc_status.png', 0, 2, 250, 30, "", "", "", true, 550,'', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
```

Can someone say the given parameters are correct for the LOGO dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of proportional ratio not maintain with given height and width so you need to set proper height and width as per your resize dimension and you can achieve it by using below code.

```
$path = JURI::root().'images/myvc_status.png';//Get image path

list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($path); 

//Find proportional ratio
$maxHeight = 250;//New height
$maxWidth = 30;//New width
$ratio = min($maxHeight / $height, $maxWidth / $width); 
$newHeight = ceil($height * $ratio); 
$newWidth = ceil($width * $ratio);
```

Now you can use `$newHeight` and `$newWidth` dimension into `$pdf->Image()` instead '250' and '30'.

Hope this helps you. Feel free to contact, in case of any query/concern regarding this.

Thanks!